# Java generics type parameters

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class MyObject {
}

public interface Dao<T extends MyObject> {
}

public abstract class JsonDao<T extends MyObject> implements Dao<T> {
}

public abstract class SqliteDao<T extends MyObject> implements Dao<T> {
}

public interface DaoFactory<*????*> {
    public *????* getDao(Class<? extends MyObject> objectClass);
}
```

Now what I'd like is for getDao to be able to instanciate both JsonDao and SqliteDao, but parametrized with a class extending MyObject, basically something like this:

```
public interface DaoFactory<T<? extends MyObject> extends Dao<? extends MyObject>> {
    public <U extends MyObject> T<U> getDao(Class<U> objectClass);
}
```

Is something similar even possible or does type erasure prevent it?

Comment: This isn't really an issue with type erasure. Java just doesn't have a feature for a syntactical construct like `T<U>`.

Comment: `interface DaoFactory<U extends MyObject, T extends Dao<U>>` ?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee I can't because the factory should instanciate Daos for multiple classes extending MyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `DaoFactory` as follows:

```
public interface DaoFactory<D extends Dao<? extends MyObject>> {

    <T extends MyObject> D getDao(Class<T> type);
}
```

Then, `JsonDaoFactory` could be implemented as follows:

```
public class JsonDaoFactory implements DaoFactory<JsonDao<? extends MyObject>> {

    private final Map<Class<? extends MyObject>, JsonDao<? extends MyObject>> daos =
            new HashMap<>();

    public JsonDaoFactory() {
        daos.put(Contact.class, new JsonContactDao());
        daos.put(Customer.class, new JsonCustomerDao());
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends MyObject> JsonDao<T> getDao(Class<T> type) {
        return (JsonDao<T>) daos.get(type);
    }
}
```

I've used a `Map` to make every descendant of `MyObject` match its corresponding `JsonDao` (here I've used `Contact` and `Customer`, and `JsonContactDao` and `JsonCustomerDao`, respectively). I've suppressed an unchecked cast warning because I'm explicitly filling the map in the constructor, so I'm sure there won't be a `ClassCastException`.

For completeness, here's the code for `SqliteDaoFactory`:

```
public class SqliteDaoFactory implements DaoFactory<SqliteDao<? extends MyObject>> {

    private final Map<Class<? extends MyObject>, SqliteDao<? extends MyObject>> daos =
            new HashMap<>();

    public SqliteDaoFactory() {
        daos.put(Contact.class, new SqliteContactDao());
        daos.put(Customer.class, new SqliteCustomerDao());
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends MyObject> SqliteDao<T> getDao(Class<T> type) {
        return (SqliteDao<T>) daos.get(type);
    }
}
```

The code for both factories is almost duplicated, but I couldn't find a way to solve this.

Here's how to use these factories:

```
JsonDaoFactory jsonDaoFactory = new JsonDaoFactory();
JsonDao<Contact> contactJsonDao = jsonDaoFactory.getDao(Contact.class);
JsonDao<Customer> customerJsonDao = jsonDaoFactory.getDao(Customer.class);

SqliteDaoFactory sqliteDaoFactory = new SqliteDaoFactory();
SqliteDao<Contact> contactSqliteDao = sqliteDaoFactory.getDao(Contact.class);
SqliteDao<Customer> customerSqliteDao = sqliteDaoFactory.getDao(Customer.class);
```

Comment: Yeah but I posted only a fragment of my class hierarchy, I use the genericity further down in the concrete classes implementing DaoFactory.

Comment: Yes I think you're on to something like @Aarjav below, I'll try that tomorrow and I will let you know :)

Comment: Okay your code works, but I'm still stuck at instanciation: I have multiple concrete implementations of JsonDao, ie.: JsonContactDao (Contact extends MyObject, JsonContactDao extends JsonDao<Contact>). I can't find a way to instantiate a JsonContactDao in getDao.

Comment: Same functions with differents parameters (file name for json, different fields to load in Contact and Customer). The problem is I'm trying to "inherit" both the storage type (Json, Sqlite, etc.) and the entity (Contact/Customer) and at some point I can't reconcile the two.

Comment: That's very nice of you. If you vanna see the whole mess my code is here: https://bitbucket.org/GaetanL/glace/src, in glace/app/src/main/java/com/gaetanl/gl/persistence/ for the abstract/sdk part and glace/app/src/main/java/com/gaetanl/glace/persistence/ for the concrete implementation.

Comment: SqliteDaos will share a database Handler, JsonDaos will share a path to save files, later I may implement WebserviceDaos that will share infos about the URLs and authentication tokens etc. The idea is to be able to do things like MySubObject o = persistenceManager.read(MySubObject.class, id) regardless of SubObject class and the data soucre.

Comment: I edited my code and pushed on bitbucket.org/GaetanL/gl and bitbucket.org/GaetanL/glace if you want a working example (with Sqlite, it's an Android app but you can still check the code if you dont wanna deploy the app). It's working almost as I want except there are unchecked casts in PersistenceManager, which I think could be avoided but I didn't find how yet.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your needs?

```
public interface DaoFactory<O extends MyObject, D extends Dao<O>> extends Dao<O> {
    public D getDao(Class<O> objectClass);
    //or for any subclass
    public <RO extends O, RD extends D<RO>> RD getSubDao(Class<RO> objectSubclass);

    //or maybe this
    public <RO extends O> Dao<RO> getSimpleSubDao(Class<RO> objectSubclass);
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising! I will test this tommorow I'll let you know!